# envio datos excel con macro

Tags: excel

El codigo es para unas 30 celdas, solo pongo las primeras, lo que tengo es lo siguiente:
                                                                                                             Sub enviar_datos()

' enviar_datos Macro
' envia datos a hoja Apertura

```
Sheets("ASIENTOS").Select
Range("C3").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("APERTURA ").Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
```

(...)
End Sub
                                                                                                                  .  El hecho es que he conseguido que se copien los datos de las  celdas  en otra hoja donde dichos valores deben ir seguidos en una única linea para ser aceptados por el destinatario. El problema es que al borrar la hoja de ingreso de datos y volver a rellenarla con otros datos diferentes, al  enviar, me sobreescribe la linea anteriormente copiada. Yo  necesito  que se envíen a la linea siguiente sin sobreescribir la anterior. No se si me explico. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Este código puede servirte, pero tendrás que adaptarlo a tus rangos y tamaños.

Lo único que hace es copiar el rango `C3:E3` de la hoja ASIENTOS en la última fila en blanco de la hoja APERTURA en las columnas A,B y C

```
Sub test()
Dim UF As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("APERTURA")
    UF = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

With ThisWorkbook
    .Worksheets("ASIENTOS").Range("C3:E3").Copy .Worksheets("apertura").Range("A" & UF + 1 & ":C" & UF + 1)
End With

End Sub
```

Mi hoja Apertura antes de ejecutar la macro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi hoja ASIENTOS con los datos a copiar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi hoja APERTURA **después** de ejecutar la macro varias veces:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes ver, cada vez que copia lo hace en la línea siguiente.

Adapta el código a tus necesidades y nos cuentas a ver qué tal